# Why am I seeing Error: 413 request entity too large in nginx?

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, nginx, file-upload

I have a problem when downloading large images, approximately more than 2 megabats.

`POST https://apis.mysite.com/apis/auth/ads net::ERR_FAILED 413 (Payload Too Large)`

I don't know what the problem is.

In the Nginx settings I specified `client_max_body_size 100M`;

```
    worker_processes  1;

    events {
        worker_connections  1024;
    }



    http {



        include       mime.types;
        default_type  application/octet-stream;

        sendfile        on;
        keepalive_timeout  65;


        ssl_certificate ./ssl/mysite.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key ./ssl/mysite.key;


        client_max_body_size 100M;

        upstream apispring {

                server 127.0.0.1:8080;
            }




         server {

            listen              443 ssl;
            server_name  apis.mysite.com;  

            location / {
            proxy_pass http://apispring;


             }

         }



         server {


            listen              443 ssl;
            server_name         mysite.com www.mysite.com;       

            location / {
                root   html;
                try_files $uri $uri$args $uri$args/ /index.html;
            }

        }



    }
```

I also specified the Spring Boot settings

```
    server.port = 8080

    server.tomcat.threads.max = 200
    server.tomcat.connection-timeout = 5s
    server.tomcat.max-swallow-size = 2MB
    server.tomcat.max-http-form-post-size = 50MB

    server.max-http-request-header-size = 8KB

    spring.servlet.multipart.max-file-size = 50MB
    spring.servlet.multipart.max-request-size = 50MB
```

I also use Angular

```
    previewImages: Set<string> = new Set();



    submit() {



        const ads: any = {
          phone: '1111111111',
          email: email@email.email,
        }



        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append('ads', JSON.stringify(ads))

        let num = this.previewImages.size;
        let count: number = 0

        for (const [value] of this.previewImages.entries()) {
          formData.append(`img${count}`, value)
          count = count + 1
          if (count === num) {
            count = 0
          }

        }


        this.httpRS.addAds(formData).subscribe({
          next: () => {
            //
          }

        });


    }
```

And my Spring Boot controller class

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/apis/auth")
    public class Ads {




        @PostMapping(value = "/ads", produces = "application/json")
        public viod addAds(@RequestParam(value = "img0", required = false) String img1,
                           @RequestParam(value = "img1", required = false) String img2,
                           @RequestParam(value = "ads") String ads) {

            // body

        }


    }
```

**Please tell me why this error occurs?**

Answer (score 1):

You got this error because your request data is not  `"multipart/form-data"` content type if you are doing file uploading. To handle such request you need to add a parameter of type `MultipartFile` where you expect to receive files.

```
@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile[] files)
```

Name each `file` with the same name to get it easy in the controller method.

---

If you have more questions, then you should refer to original [docs](https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/) to get started.

---

> **Why am I seeing Error: 413 “Request Entity Too Large” in Nginx?**
>
> This is happening because your nginx server does not allow you to upload a file that is larger than the defined size in nginx config file.
>
> To solve it, you have to modify your nginx configuration.
>
> Follow the step to add/modify your nginx config file:
>
> 1. Connect to your nginx server with your terminal.
>    `ssh user@my_server`
> 2. Go to the config location and open it
>    `sudo vim /etc/nginx/nginx.conf`
> 3. Adding/Modifying the `client_max_body_size` variable.
>    If you find it, just increase its size to 100M,
>    If it doesn’t exist, then you can add the below code inside and at the end of HTTP settings:
>    `client_max_body_size 100M;`
> 4. Restart nginx to apply the changes
>    `sudo service nginx restart`

Comment: I did it. It does not help

Comment: @Jack I will keep this answer for future readers may be it will help them.